# React Native Redux - initialize default state from asyncstorage

Tags: react-native

i'm developing an android application whereby my screen has to depends on whether the user is logged in or not. The login data is stored inside the AsyncStorage.

By the time when the apps start, it should get the data from AsyncStorage and make it as the default state. How can i achieve that ?

Below is my redux structure

index.android.js

```
import {
  AppRegistry,
} from 'react-native';

import Root from './src/scripts/Root.js';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('reduxReactNavigation', () => Root);
```

Root.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, AsyncStorage } from "react-native";
import { Provider, connect } from "react-redux";
import { addNavigationHelpers } from 'react-navigation';

import getStore from "./store";
import { AppNavigator } from './routers';

const navReducer = (state, action) => {
    const newState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state);
    return newState || state;
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    nav: state.nav
});

const user = {};

class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <AppNavigator
            navigation={addNavigationHelpers({
                dispatch: this.props.dispatch,
                state: this.props.nav
            })}
        />
    );
  }
}

const AppWithNavigationState = connect(mapStateToProps)(App);

const store = getStore(navReducer);

export default function Root() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <AppWithNavigationState />
        </Provider>
    );
}
```

user reducers

```
import {
    REGISTER_USER,
    UPDATE_USER,
    LOGIN_USER
} from '../../actions/actionTypes';

import { handleActions } from 'redux-actions';

**// here is the default state, i would like to get from asyncstorage**
const defaultState = {
  isLoggedIn: false,
  user:{},
};

export const user = handleActions({
  REGISTER_USER: {
    next(state, action){
      return { ...state, user: action.payload, isLoggedIn: true }
    }
  },
  LOGIN_USER: {
    next(state, action){
      return { ...state, user: action.payload, isLoggedIn: true }
    }
  },
}, defaultState);
```

Comment: you can give the initial state to createStore function: http://redux.js.org/docs/api/createStore.html. You can read data from async storage and pass it to createStore() function which will set the appropriate state.

Comment: @AnkitAggarwal Could you provide example on where should i get the data from asyncstorage and pass into createstore ?

it's because the asyncstorage is asynchronous, i not sure what is the good practice to initialize it

Comment: read about redux-persis (https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) and use this concept (https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/blob/master/docs/recipes.md#delay-render-until-rehydration-complete). No need to use redux-persist as such but you can use the rehydration idea from here. Check the second link for delayed rendering

Comment: @AnkitAggarwal got it, thanks ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the component lifecycle method componentWillMount to fetch the data from AsyncStorage and when the data arrive you can change the state.